# PHP - Display Username in Header after Logged in

Tags: php, html, sql

I've just learnt how to create a simple logging in script.

At the moment the user just logs in and it re-directs you to the home page with no conformation of being logged in.

*I have this header:*
[image]

Just to the left of the little home icon i would like $username to show of who has logged in.

**index.php** *(which is where that header is)*

```
<table class="header-container">
<tr>
    <td style="width: 40%; text-align: left;"><a href="index.php"><img class="hover-cursor" src="Images/TEAMS_Logo.png"></a></td>
    <td style="width: 10%;" class="custom-header custom-font">TEAMS 
        <span style="color: #cc2020" class="custom-font">W</span><span style="color: #1a488c" class="custom-font">I</span><span style="color: #2a9e56" class="custom-font">K</span><span style="color: #d87f0a" class="custom-font">I </span><span style="font-size: 30px;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></span></td>
    <td style="width: 40%;">

    <!-- Username to go here -->

        <table style="text-align: right; width: 100%">
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align: right;"><span style="font-size: 24px; text-align: right;" class="hvr-icon-grow"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
</tr>
```

*When i click login it runs* **login_form.php**

```
<?php include 'connectionDetails.php'; ?>

<?php session_start(); ?>

<?php 

if (isset($_POST['username']) and isset($_POST['password'])) 
{
    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password = $_REQUEST['password'];


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?";

    $user = $username; 
    $pass = $password;

    $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array(&$user, &$pass));

    if( !$stmt ) 
    {
        die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }   

    sqlsrv_execute($stmt);

    if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt) === true) 
    {
        header('location: index.php');
    }

}

?>
```

So 3 things.

1) How do i display a username in the header of the index page for the person logged in?

2) What do i add to login_form.php to bring up an alert box if the credentials entered are incorrect?

3) Is there a way to hide the login button once a user has logged in?

Comment: Just a quik observation - it looks like you're storing user's passwords in plaintext in the database (which is a fairly major security risk). Also, no sanitation of user submitted data is performed before using it in the query (a prime route for SQL injection attacks). It would be better if A - you store a hash of the password in the database and use a hash of the user submitted password in the query, and B - learn about prepared statements using PDO. Check the manual and StackOverflow for plenty of examples

Comment: Ok i shall take a look, thank you

Comment: I thought i had used a prepared statement in here, i looked at the documents on the PHP site for sqlsrv_prepare and this is what it shown, so is my statement not prepared?

Comment: Sorry - my bad. I'm used to PDO and I didn't look at your code properly. it's been a long year and my brain is frazzled

Comment: No problem, i appreciate it the comment none the less

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of sessions : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

> 1) How do i display a username in the header of the index page for the
>   person logged in?

Store the username in the session when loggin

> 2) What do i add to login_form.php to bring up an alert box if the
>   credentials entered are incorrect?

```
if (sqlsrv_execute($stmt) === true) 
{
    header('location: index.php');
}
else {
    // not logged
}
```

> 3) Is there a way to hide the login button once a user has logged in?

Check if session exists

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i'll give the article on Sessions a read because they seem super useful and i'll give the rest of it a go :)

Comment: Oh and just a quick question for storing the username in a session, do i need to do an include on my main index.html to include my login_form.php so it knows where $username has come from?

Comment: $username will by displayed via php so you may want to have an index.php wich is able to display the user name within the html view

Comment: apologies i meant to put index.php xD so would i need to include my login_form.php or not since it would be that that has all my $username information?

Answer (score 1):

1) You could store the username in the $_SESSION and then echo it where you want it.

2) You could add another value to the Session or post when the condition is false and then echo out some html

3) You could store a variable in the session that tells the Loginbutton to show up or not. small example:

```
if ($userloggedin == true) {
   //do not echo the button
} else {
  //echo the button
}
```